# spring aws: sqs messages not received

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

Here my straightforward code:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SQSEventsService {

    private static final String MESSENGER_QUEUE = "messengerQueue";

    private final SqsTemplate template;

    @SqsListener(MESSENGER_QUEUE)
    public void listen(String message) {
        log.debug("Message received");
        log.trace("Message received: {}", message);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void publish() {
        log.debug("Sending message");
        this.template.send(MESSENGER_QUEUE, "payload string");
        log.debug("Message sent");
    }
}
```

My service is running but I don't quite figure out why I don't receive messages.

Here my queues:

`$ aws sqs list-queue --profile localstack --region us-east-1`:

```json
{
  "QueueUrls": [
    "http://sqs.us-east-1.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/MessengerQueue"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Could I debug sqs queue using aws cli? I mean, how could I receive messages from sqs queue using `aws-cli`?

Comment: If you want to use AWS SQS within a Spring Boot project, look at using AWS Java SDK V2 and specifically the SQS API. There are no issues reading and writing to SQS queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can receive messages from sqs queue using aws-cli.
This example receives up to 10 available messages, returning all available attributes.

Command:

```
aws sqs receive-message --queue-url http://sqs.us-east-1.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/MessengerQueue --attribute-names All --message-attribute-names All --max-number-of-messages 10
```

Doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/receive-message.html

Also, your queue name in AWS is "MessengerQueue" (with a capital "M") but in your code, you are trying to listen and send to "messengerQueue" (with a small "m"). AWS SQS queue names are case-sensitive.

So, you need to change your code to:

```
private static final String MESSENGER_QUEUE = "MessengerQueue";
```